# Extend value to arithmetic mean

Tags: statistics

Might be a quite stupid question and I'm not sure if it belongs here or to math.

My problem:

I have several elements of type X which have a boolean attribute Y.

To calculate the percentage of elements where Y is true, I count all X where Y is true and divide it by the number of elements.

But I don't want to iterate all the time above all elements to update that percentage-value.

My idea was:

If I had 33% for 3 elements, and am adding a fourth one where Y is true:

```
(0.33 * 3 + 1) / 4 = 0.4975
```

Obviously that does not work well because of the 0.33.

Is there any way for getting an accurate solution without iteration or saving the number of items where Y is true?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? (If none, then it's probably not a programming question and doesn't belong here.)

Comment: But it asks how the datastructure and algorithm should look like, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a count of the total number of elements and of the "true" ones.  Global vars, object member variables, whatever.   I assume that sometime back when the program is starting, you have zero elements.   Every time an element is added, removed, or its boolean attribute changes, increment or decrement those counts as appropriate.  You'll never have to iterate over the list (except maybe for testing) but at the cost of every change to the list having to include fiddling with those variables.

Comment: Thanks.. What you propose is what I ment by "Is there any way for getting an accurate solution without iteration or saving the number of items where Y is true?". The downside of this is that you store the same information twice (because the number of Y = true can be aggregated from the rest)

Comment: But after rethinking that, the same thing is true for my percentage-value.. So I have to dye one death. Thanks for your answer (:

Answer (score 2):

Your idea doesn't work because 0.33 does not equal 1/3.  It's an approximation.  If you take the exact value, you get the right answer:

```
(1/3 * 3 + 1) / 4 = (1 + 1) / 4 = 1/2
```

My question is, if you can store the value of 33% without iterating, why not just store the values of 1 and 3 and calculate them?  That is, just keep a running total of the number of true values and number of objects.  Increment when you get new ones.  Calculate on demand.  It's not necessary to iterate every time is way.